# Getting notified when an I2C-Value changes in C++

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, i2c

I recently started experimenting with I2C-Hardware on my raspberry pi. Following this tutorial [Using the I2C interface](https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/i2c/using-the-i2c-interface) I already know how to read and set values. However, the program I want to realize needs the current value on a specific address all the time. So, I made a thread and query the value constantly in a never ending loop, which seems primitive to me. Is it possible to get notified in an event-like manner when a value on an I2C-adress changes?
A platform independend solution would also be much welcomed.

Comment: What is your I2C device measuring? A voltage or a temperature or a force something?

Comment: Check to see if the device you are monitoring also has an output you can tie to an interrupt or some other sort of GPIO you can monitor so that you'll know when it is worth your time to read the device.

Comment: @JohnFilleau: A voltage

Comment: @user4581301: Thats new territory to me.I will see what I can find on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get what I wanted.

I use the following repeater for the I2C-Bus: [link](https://www.horter.de/doku/I2C-Repeater-PCA9517-PI+T_db.pdf) and it turns out there is a soldering bridge (LB2) you can set that sets a signal on GPIO17 whenever a value on the I2C-Bus changes since it has last been changed. I can now listen on this events accordingly.

Comment: Well done, and thank you for sharing your findings back with the Stack community. I'll delete my earlier comment as it is incorrect, or at least potentially misleading. You can accept your own answer by the way

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the I2C bus has no interrupt capability. So with only I2C, all you can do is poll the chip for a certain event to happen or value to change.

Most chips do have an interrupt line (sometimes even more than one) that can be programmed to trigger on certain events. The behavior of this line depends on the chip. Usually it needs to be enabled (using I2C commands) and it needs to be linked to a GPIO input line. For these, interrupt support is available.